# How are chapters handled in Typo3 Neos?

Tags: typo3-flow, neoscms

I want to use **chapters** and **chapter-menu** as a e.g. image gallery, reference module or other collections in Typo3 Neos.

As there are multiple domains with different content in my installation i have a problem with the NodeTypes.yaml:
All my site packages are based on NeosDemoTypo3Org. Because i don't want to have multiple entries "chapter", "chapter menu", "youtube" and so on, i deleted the NodeTypes.yaml in my copies of NeosDemoTypo3Org (which is still installed).

When i add a page with content element "chapter menu" to a package and put some chapters in it, the chapter overview is only displayed, if am putting the NodeTypes.yaml back into my package configuration. But then again i have multiple entries of the same thing.

How/where can i configure this to fit my needs?

Answer (score 0):

That should be no problem. Just having the Chapter etc. in one NodeTypes.yaml is enough for now (until we implemented separation per Site which we want to have at some point). But I guess you adapted all occurances of "TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org" in your TypoScript to match the new package name? You need to of course change that back for everything that is related to those NodeTypes. The TypoScript must point to the correct name for this NodeType. And you have to declare the TypoScript in each package because TypoScript is NOT shared in contrast to the NodeTypes.

What you could do is create a "base package" that contains the NodeTypes and TypoScript (and Tempaltes for those) and include the TypoScript in each of your Site packages.